# Core Data Insert with existing relationship weird issue

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Core data insert new data with existing relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293301/core-data-insert-new-data-with-existing-relationship)

I got problem with core data, I had a table that exactly look like this

User (relationship with) Rack (relationship with) RackItem

Insert look like this

```
NSArray *result =
    [[CoreModel sharedCoreModel] fetchDataWithEntity:@"Rack" predicate:predicate];
Rack *item = [result lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@",item);
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[CoreModel sharedCoreModel] managedObjectContext];
RackItem *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RackItem"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[object setRack:item];
//[[object rack] setUser:item];

[context insertObject:object];
[context save:nil];
```

The result after followed insert

**Before Insert**

```
 1|9|2|0|0||||248|52|||1|||||||
 2|9|2|0|0|||||||||||||||
 3|9|2|0|0|||||||||||||||
 4|9|2|0|0|||||||||||||||
 5|9|1|0|0|1||||||||||||||
 sqlite> select *from zrackitem;
```

**After Insert**

```
 1|9|2|0|0||||248|52|||1|||||||
 2|9|2|0|0|||||||||||||||
 3|9|2|0|0|||||||||||||||
 4|9|2|0|0|||||||||||||||
 5|9|2|0|0|||||||||||||||
 6|9|1|0|0|1||||||||||||||
 sqlite> select *from zrackitem;
```

it shows that every time I insert the existing row of zrack variable is gone.

Comment: I'm sorry that's is my question too but this is an updated version of that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your relationship from Rack to RackItem is 1 to 1. It should be one to many.

Comment: Seems that I need to set it in core data inspector view, I forgot to set it. Thanks a lot